# Can I run a Windows 8 app on a Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

i'm currently developing windows 8 Application using visual studio 2012 with C# and .Net.

I'm used template from visual studio 2012 (in new project -> Installed -> other template -> other languages -> visual C# -> window store -> blank app xaml)

then i execute it on the simulator (then windows tablet simulator appear), my question, can my application that i built can running on windows phone 7 or 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As xVir,suggested you cannot run a windows 8 app on a windows phone.

But you can use some strategies to  maximise code reuse between the apps.

- Separate UI and application logic using the MVVM pattern
- Use Portable Class Libraries(PCL) to share functionalities
- Share code with Add as Link
- Share using Windows Runtime Components
- Handling difference between WP8 and W8 platforms

For more info you can refer this [Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 app development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714089%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: how about in windows 8 tablet-pc?

Comment: @user1533670 Win8 tablet uses WinRT and not all apps that are designed for Win8 won't run on WinRT.Have a look at this [link](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/microsoft-windows-rt-windows-8/) that illustrates the usage of Win8 in WinRT. And Microsoft is expected to release tablets with Win8 Pro ,then there will be no problem in using apps.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is different project types. 
But you can share some common code between projects using libraries.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work. windows phone is diffrent platforms. if you want to run same code on windows phone 8 and windows 8 you can use the portable classess.